# Animating Just a single Marker in Google Map-Multiple Markers aspx Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I have designed Google Map aspx Page that displays multiple locations of bank-branches on the Google Map in the form of Markers. The Google map page appears as a pop-up window from another aspx page and these bank-branches are being fetched from the database. Now my requirement is to animate only one marker in Google map page(on page-load itself) which shows that location which the user selected it from the drop-down list from that another aspx page.
I don't want my all markers to get animated.

I have applied toggleBounce() function as follows but that animates all markers

> ```
> (function (Mycontent) {
>
>                     geocoder.geocode({ 'address': locarr[i] }, function (results, status) {
>
>                         if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
>                             map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
>                             var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>                                 map: map,
>                                 position: results[0].geometry.location,
>                                 icon: icon1,
>                                 info: InfoPopUp,
>                                 animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
>                             });
>
>                             function toggleBounce() {
>                                 if (marker.getAnimation() != null) {
>                                     marker.setAnimation(null);
>                                 } else {
>                                     marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
>
>                                     window.setTimeout(
>                                         function () {
>                                             marker.setAnimation(null);
>                                         },
>                                         5000);
>                                 }
>                             }
>
>                             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
>                                 InfoPopUp.open(map, marker);
>                                 InfoPopUp.setContent(Mycontent);
>                                 marker.setIcon(icon1);
>                             });
>
>                             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
>                                 InfoPopUp.close(map, marker);
>                                 marker.setIcon(icon1);
>                             });
>
>                             bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
>
>                             google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', toggleBounce);
>
>                         }   // end if
>
>                         else {
>                             alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + '\n' + status);
>                         }
>                     });     // geocoder ends  
>                 })(Mycontent);
> ```

Since i am new to the Google Maps designing, i didn't find the solution for that. Could anyone please help me out. Any help is appreciable.

Thanks in advance...